# Pagination feature in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, pagination, ignite

I need to pull data from Apache Ignite Cache and show it on JSP. Data size is in million so I need to setup Server side pagination. Apache Ignite docs does not say much about pagination except setting pageSize to query which by default is 1024. How do I pass startIndex and endIndex, basically the parameters which we pass when implementing pagination with database.
For example, I have below sample code to query cache, can we apply pagination to it by passing certain parameters.

```
public Set<String> getData(int pageSize){
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, String> config = new CacheConfiguration<>("mycache");
        config.setBackups(1);
        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(config);
        long dataSize = 30;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataSize; i++) {
            cache.put(i, String.valueOf(i));
        }

        ScanQuery<Integer, String> query = new ScanQuery<>((Integer e1, String e2) ->e1>10);
        Set<String> res = cache.query(query.setPageSize(pageSize)).getAll().stream().map(Cache.Entry::getValue).collect(toSet()); 
        System.out.println(res);
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignite provides pagination features, you can go to and fro, I have Tested in 2.3 version. I have used Spring boot. check the below code

Rest req:

http://localhost:8086/test/getOne1?page=2&size=5&city=bgr

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/getOne1")
    public Test getOneTest(String city, Pageable pageable) {

        return testService.getOneTest(city, pageable);
    }
```

Service:

```
Test getOneTest(String city, Pageable pageable);
```

Service Impl:

```
@Override
    public Test getOneTest(String city, Pageable pageable) {

        //Test one = repo1.getById(0);


        //List<Integer> subscribers = repo1.findAll(pageable);

        List<Integer> subscribers = repo1.selectAll(city, pageable);

        subscribers.forEach(x -> System.out.println("--"+ x));

        return repo1.findOne(12);
    }
```

Repo:

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "test")
public interface TestRepo extends IgniteRepository<Test, Integer>{


    @Query("SELECT subscribers FROM test where city = ?")
    List<Integer> selectAll(String city, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignite doesn't provide such support for pagination. Pagination in Ignite is just a mechanism to avoid fetching the whole data set from server nodes to the client. I.e., while you iterate through the `QueryCursor`, the client will fetch data in chunks. The size of each chunk is defined by `pageSize` property.

Having said that, you can display data on the JSP page in pages, but once you moved to the next page, you will not be able to use `QueryCursor` to go back. However, if the result set is not expected to be very large, you can call `QueryCursor.getAll()` method to get all rows and handle pagination on the application level, saving the result in the web session or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did try pageSize as you can see in code above. But it does not work. I set pageSize to 10 while no of records matching predicate are 20, I still get 20 records instead of 10.

Assuming this should work, My approach was to add pagesSize and using skip() method, pagination can be achieved. Any idea why it is returning all records irrespective of whether pageSize is set or not. ?

Answer (score 0):

Paging by using "limit m offset n" like this:

```
SqlQuery querySql = new SqlQuery(UserInfo.class, "age > ? order by username desc limit ? offset ?");    
List<Cache.Entry<Integer, UserInfo>> resultList = userInfoCache.query(querySql.setArgs(20, 2, 5)).getAll();
```

Of course, Ignite allows changing pageSize, but you need to remember that Page size is used to set the cursor. result set is stored in 'pages' in the memory, therefore, if U increase the page-size, more number of key-value pairs can be accommodated in the same page.